# Clunky animations with Framer Motion's AnimatePresence

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I created my [portfolio](https://kevinhurley23.github.io/portfolio/) using React and Framer Motion.  In the Projects section, when I click on one of the Project Cards, it opens a Project Details modal. Framer Motion's AnimatePresence handles the animation going from the Project Card to the Project Details. Sometimes this animation looks right, but I'd say more than 50% of the time the animation isn't quite right; for example, the image jumps to a different size and positon before animating to the destination size and position.

Here's the most relevant part of the code:

```
const cardVariants = {
    hidden: { opacity: 0, y: 200 },
    show: {
      opacity: 1,
      y: 0,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };

  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        className={"project-card " + tags.join(" ")}
        variants={cardVariants}
        layoutId={title}
        onClick={() => setSelectedId(title)}
      >
        <img src={thumb} />
        <div className="project-title">
          <motion.h3>{title}</motion.h3>
        </div>
      </motion.div>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {selectedId && (
          <motion.div className="modal-wrapper flex-center">
            <motion.div layoutId={selectedId} className="project-details">
              [...project detail content]
            </motion.div>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
```

And here's the entire component if you need more context: https://github.com/kevinhurley23/portfolio/blob/master/src/components/ProjectCard.jsx

Am I doing something wrong in my implementation of AnimatePresence?  By using one image in the card and a different one in the details modal, am I trying to make AnimatePresence do something it's not designed to do?